# Split URL string into columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the string:

```
URL:'ID=1!&user=xxx&depart=21&companyId=43&workOrder=67'
```

I need to get the result:

```
Sno ID user  depart companyId  workOrder
1   1! XXX   21      43         67
```

Note: the column may increase.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 5):

[Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) has an excellent set of articles on [SQLPerformance.com](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) about how to split strings, including a very thorough set of performance tests for the various mechanisms you can employ.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, you cannot take advantage of the `STRING_SPLIT()` functionality in SQL Server 2016; however you can make use of the following code that will likely perform extremely badly and give lots of people, not least Aaron, nightmares:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       varchar(8000),
   @Delimiter  char(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN (SELECT [value] = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
      FROM (SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i));
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetColsFromString
(
    @Input VARCHAR(4000)
    , @Delimiter CHAR(1)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PvtList NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000);

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SourceRows') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SourceRows;
    SELECT ss.*
    INTO #SourceRows
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@Input, @Delimiter) ss

    SET @PvtList = STUFF((
    SELECT ',[' +  SUBSTRING(sr.value, 1, CHARINDEX('=', sr.value) -1) + ']'
    FROM #SourceRows sr
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 1, '');

    SET @cmd = '
    SELECT ' + @PvtList + '
    FROM (
        SELECT ColumnName = SUBSTRING(sr.value, 1, CHARINDEX(''='', sr.value) -1)
            , ColumnValue = SUBSTRING(sr.value, CHARINDEX(''='', sr.value) + 1, LEN(sr.value))
        FROM #SourceRows sr
        ) src
    PIVOT (
        MAX(ColumnValue)
        FOR ColumnName IN (
            ' + @PvtList + '
        )
    ) pvt;';
    PRINT @cmd;
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
END
GO
EXEC dbo.GetColsFromString 'ID=1!&user=xxx&depart=21&companyId=43&workOrder=67','&';
```

The output from running the above code:

[image]

The code above builds on Aaron's `dbo.SplitStrings_XML` function, to turn a single delimited string into a result set using a PIVOT statement.  This code should work for any string passed in that has a format similar to `x=y` where `x` is the desired column name, `y` is the desired output, and `=` is the delimiter.

If you wanted to insert that result set into a table, you could use the `INSERT INTO ... EXEC ...` approach, perhaps like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ID, user, depart, companyId, workOrder)
EXEC dbo.GetColsFromString 'ID=1!&user=xxx&depart=21&companyId=43&workOrder=67','&';
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option, also involving dynamic SQL, could be, basically, to replace every `&` with a comma, put `SELECT`  in front of the string and execute the resulting query. The idea is that SQL Server allows you to represent column aliases in the form of `name = value` and the input string already consists of such name/value pairs, only the delimiter needs to be changed.

But, of course, in actual fact that would not be enough, because, first of all, the values would additionally need to be enclosed in quotation marks. As for the names, they might happen to match reserved words in SQL – that means the names would need to be quoted as well.

The simplest approach to resolving all the issues mentioned assumes that an equal sign in the input string is always a delimiter between a name and a value and an ampersand is always a delimiter between columns, and neither can ever be part of a value. Given that your input string looks very much like an HTML parameter list, I consider those assumptions reasonable enough.

So, the solution's logical steps would be these:

1. Replace every `&` with a `', [` (close the preceding column's value, comma as a delimiter between the columns, start quoting the next identifier).
2. Replace every `=` with a `] = '` (close the preceding identifier, put back the `=`, start quoting the following value).
3. Put `[` at the beginning of the string (start quoting the first identifier) and `'` at the end (end of quoting of the last value).
4. Put `SELECT`  at the beginning.
5. Execute the resulting query.

And here is the above translated to Transact-SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'SELECT [' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@input, '&', ''', ['), '=', '] = ''') + ''';';
PRINT @sql;  -- if you want to see what the resulting query looks like
EXECUTE (@sql);  -- this executes the dynamic query, which outputs a row of columns
```

The `@input` in the above script is the input string passed as a parameter. It would probably be best to implement the script as a stored procedure. An example of such a procedure can be found and tested [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/328a8/1).